# Fill in the NaN values with mean value grouped by key in a dataset (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I fill the NaN values of each column in a dataset with the mean value of the specific column the NaN is, grouped by a key characteristic (in my case Location)?

Eg. I have a column named PM2.5, and there are some missing values in some rows of some monitors. Those monitors are in different places (I organized them by a column that has its locations). I want to fill the missing values of each column (in this case, PM2.5) with the mean of the values that were recorded by the monitors in the same location/area for each specific element/column (in this case PM2.5).

I tried

```
df= df.groupby('LocationA')['PM2.5'].transform('mean')
df['PM2.5'].fillna(s, inplace=True)
```

but I get keyerror, I was planning to do that in a for while loop.

Here is a screenshot of my dataset.
[image]

Comment: could you show a snippet of your dataframe?

Comment: @catasaurus sure, I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo in your example code? I approached the problem from scratch and arrived at the exact same right-hand side code:

```
s = df.groupby('LocationA')['PM2.5'].transform('mean')
df['PM2.5'] = df['PM2.5'].fillna(s)
```

Comment: oh yes, LocationA should be Location but still will not work. Feel free to suggest another solution

Comment: Could you elaborate on "still will not work"? What is the complete error message that you get?

Comment: The suspected typo is the left-hand side of the first line: I think it should be `s = df.groupby`, not `df = df.groupby`

Comment: This is the error I get:   
' line 100, in <module>
    df['CO2'].fillna(s, inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 389, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'CO2'`

Comment: I see you're using `s` to fill missing values in a different column, `CO2`. Before doing this, you would have to recreate s as follows: `s = df.groupby('LocationA')['CO2'].transform('mean')`

Comment: I tried, I get an error at that line.   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 882, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'A' ..I think i have to mention somewhere which columns or smth